# Why this confirm function doesn't go on?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem with my js code. If I click ok or cancel my records are deleted.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['wybrany_projekt'])) {
    while($row_1 = $result_1->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo"<tr><td value='{$row_1['id']}'><a href='mainpage.search.delete.information.php?del=$row_1[id]'><div id='$row_1[id]' onclick='myFunction()';>[x]</div></a></td>\n";
}
}?> 

<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var r=confirm("Delete this row?");
    if (r==true) {
     window.location.href="mainpage.search.delete.information.php";
     return true
     }
</script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, can you explain better your problem?

Comment: You do not cancel the click event and why would you use a GET request to do a delete... that is a bad idea.

Comment: `function myFunction() { return confirm("Delete this row?") }` ?

Comment: Let me explain to you better my project. I created a table and it's displayed in while loop. Also, I created a column "delete". To protect by random delete a row I'd to implement a javascript alert window it asks a user again that want to delete a row (confirmation OK or Cancel). I have it but when I click on Cancel row is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error. You are missing one parenthesis (enclosing } character):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var r=confirm("Delete this row?");
    if (r==true) {
     window.location.href="mainpage.search.delete.information.php";
     return true
     }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing a '}' to close function myFunction(). This may fix your code.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var r=confirm("Delete this row?");
if (r==true) {
 window.location.href="mainpage.search.delete.information.php";
 return true
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have a } character in my code. I copied my code without this character, sorry.